# how to access the cell content outside the function

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I need to call the cell label outside of the `cellForRowAt indexPath` function but it show the error any one help me to solve this issues 
here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell: FeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleVideoChageSlider), for:.valueChanged)
         cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.videolabl.text="check"
          return cell
    }

 @IBAction func GetUpdatesButtonTouched(_ sender: AnyObject) {
//how do i call the cell fuction 
 //cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleVideoChageSlider), for:.valueChanged )
}
```

I need to call this `cell.label` to inside of the fuction of:

```
@IBAction func handleVideoChageSlider(_ sender: UISlider)  {
    print(sender.value)
//like cell.videolabel.text="change name"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**To access Cell Content**

Please assign indexPath with section no as well item No.

```
 let index = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
 let refCell = tblListingURL.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! FeedCell
 refCell.videolabl.text = "NewText"
```

Comment: Maninderjit you are accessing index 0 what for multiple cells?

Comment: We can use same code for multiple as well. we should know about indexPaths

Comment: Yes Maninderjit... So have you gone throught the complete question?

Comment: I think it should be like: let index = NSIndexPath(forItem: sender.tag, inSection: 0)

Comment: we have to create reference for each cell in table we are going to access

Comment: Yes , you are also right, I just explain the method for accessing cell .Its developer technique how to pass cellIndex and section Index. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get the cell content:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

  let cell: FeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

  cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleVideoChageSlider), for:.valueChanged)
  cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.videolabl.text="check"
  return cell
}

@IBAction func handleVideoChageSlider(_ sender: UISlider)  {
  print(sender.value)

  //tableView is your table view object
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! FeedCell

  //now you can get your label
  cell.Yourlabel.text = "Hello India" 
}
```

Comment: Correct animesh

Comment: Thanks For the Responese if i use ur code it shows me : Argument labels '(forItem:, inSection:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: @Agaram You might be using **swift 3** and the syntax are a bit changed hence you are getting the argument label do not match error. You can change the following code to get rid of the error

`let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as! FeedCell`

Comment: @Agaram with the above code in comment you could get the cell instance and from the cell instance you could access your cell

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a cell in the function as below:

```
@IBAction func handleVideoChageSlider(_ sender: UISlider)  {
    print(sender.value)

    let cell: FeedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! FeedCell

    cell.videolabl.text="change name"
}
```

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Comment: how can you say that this is a dulicate answer @DheerajD?

Comment: hi Dude plese check my update qustion when i work to use your code  it wont work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can access your cell content outside the function like this :

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! FeedCell

print(currentCell.videoLabel.text)
```

Comment: Its not Working Dude

Comment: tag: Optional(<AVPlayer: 0x79fbdbf0>)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: can you please debug the code and let me know on which line its crashing.... so i can resolve this issue.....

Comment: @IBAction func GetUpdatesButtonTouched(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.currentTitle == "Play" { currentPlayer.play()
                sender.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.normal)
                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
                let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! FeedCell  //print(currentCell.videoLabel.text)
                currentCell.slider.tag=indexPath.row
                currentCell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleVideoChageSlider), for:.valueChanged )
            }

Comment: here i wont get any selct row when click the paly bitton ineed to call the cell functionlity

Comment: you should add break point and tap your button and check the cell.slider showing any value or not...

Comment: try to add this line:      let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FeedCell

Comment: let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! FeedCell i add this line already

Comment: let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! here i got the bad exx error

Comment: bro... undo the code and plz debug and let me know on which line its crashing and tell me that what value it is showing for cell.slider

Comment: i think the problem is tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!this line

Comment: use this line .... tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! FeedCell

Comment: then what about the indexpath

Answer (score 0):

I've not checked all answers  instead ,I tried. Not all worked due to not getting indexpath,

In this case with swift 5,Xcode 10.3 one thing worked for me. Let me know if something wrong, Thankyou.

```swift
let cell: cellCarerDailySchedual = tblDailySchedual.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! cellCarerDailySchedual
```